# GraphQL Input type declaration for Mutation

Tags: java, graphql, graphql-java

I'm new to GraphQL and after some coding I bumped into a problem with declaring an Input type for a Mutation.
Here's my Schema:

```
type Test {
  id: ID!
  label: String!
}

extend type Query {
  test(id : ID!): Test
  listTests (where: myWhereCondition, orderBy: myOrderByCondition): [Test!]!
}

extend type Mutation {
  createTest(label: String!, testTypes: TestTypesInput): Test!
}

input TestTypesInput {
  testTypes: [IdInput]
}

input IdInput {
  id: ID!
}
```

When I run my app, I get the error

> Caused by: graphql.kickstart.tools.SchemaError: Expected type
> 'IdInput' to be a GraphQLInputType, but it wasn't!  Was a type only
> permitted for object types incorrectly used as an input type, or
> vice-versa?   at
> graphql.kickstart.tools.SchemaParser.determineType(SchemaParser.kt:400)
> ~[graphql-java-tools-11.0.1.jar:na]   at
> graphql.kickstart.tools.SchemaParser.determineInputType(SchemaParser.kt:417)
> ~[graphql-java-tools-11.0.1.jar:na]   at
> graphql.kickstart.tools.SchemaParser.determineInputType(SchemaParser.kt:410)
> ~[graphql-java-tools-11.0.1.jar:na]   at
> graphql.kickstart.tools.SchemaParser.createInputObject(SchemaParser.kt:179)
> ~[graphql-java-tools-11.0.1.jar:na]   at
> graphql.kickstart.tools.SchemaParser.parseSchemaObjects(SchemaParser.kt:79)
> ~[graphql-java-tools-11.0.1.jar:na]   at
> graphql.kickstart.tools.SchemaParser.makeExecutableSchema(SchemaParser.kt:112)
> ~[graphql-java-tools-11.0.1.jar:na]   at
> graphql.kickstart.tools.boot.GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration.graphQLSchema(GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration.java:143)
> ~[graphql-kickstart-spring-boot-autoconfigure-tools-11.1.0.jar:na]

I can't understand what I'm missing, to me the "IdInput" is well declared as `input` and reading some other examples it looks correct to me, but it clearly isn't. I tried to declare che IdInput as `type` insted of `input`, but it obviously doesn't work. How can I pass a list of input objects into an input array?
If you need more informations I'll add them, at the moment I'm just mixing some declaration to come up with the correct one, with no success.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: The schema looks fine to me, the error must come from somewhere else. Maybe is `IdIntput` declared as a `type` somewhere else in your schema? Are you sure the failure comes from the code you shared? Have you tried a simple mutation, e.g. `test(id: IdInput) ID`, see whether this passes?

Comment: You're right, it came from somewhere else: in the Mutation resolver I declared wrong the TestTypesInput in the method's signature. Actually, I wasn't changing it because I saw this error and focused on the GraphQL schema thinking the problem was there and once fixed I could set the method's signature accordingly. Really disappointing to find out. Thank you for your time!

Comment: No worries, glad you found out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find out this was a misleading error, since the GraphQL schema couldn't fetch with the Mutation Resolver's signature method. Instead of pointing out that part, it kept to break in the GraphQL Schema declaration.
Once declared the signature method accordingly to the Schema, everything worked out like a charm.
Hope it may help someone with this misleading error handling.